# Emacs/TextMate code completion for Erlang?

Tags: emacs, erlang, textmate, code-completion

[ESense](http://esense.sourceforge.net/) looks dead; what are your recommendations for Erlang code completion in Emacs? It doesn't have to be fancy (ESense built an index from the Erlang source); even something that just uses Erlang's `module_info/0` and `module_info/1` functions for introspection of function names would help.

If one isn't available in Emacs, can you recommend one for TextMate?

Answer (score 4):

I've used auto-complete successfully.

- site: http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/
- code: https://github.com/m2ym/auto-complete/

and added this to my .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/dev/emacs/auto-complete")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/dev/emacs/auto-complete/dict")
(ac-config-default)

; ... after loading erlang-mode

(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'erlang-mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about distel already?

- See Bill Clementson [summarize distel mode and its features](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070528.html).

Answer (score 0):

distel should be able to compete functions names using information from running node

Answer (score -1):

I've one working that I use for my own development. Its at,

http://github.com/rajivr/erlang.tmbundle

Feel free to try it and ping me if you have any issues.